# Do I need to close wcf connection?

Tags: c++, web-services, wcf, soap, command-line-interface

Do I need to close WCF CLI application on each method call ? As I googled, got many sites and stack overflow answer how it can be properly closed.

But in an situation where you have created an wrapper library for WCF CLI, if user has not used for long time, it may timeout and needed to close again and reconnect. To avoid this do I need to close connection for every method call ?.

Can I have an suggestion over this.